# Can not find symbol - method Size()

Tags: arraylist

I have been getting trouble with my program and can't figure out why I am getting this error which has been bugging me. Any suggestion will be of huge assistance! I don't know if i am missing something or something like that. I have correctly imported the Array Class.

```
private String title;
private ArrayList<Student> students;
private int courseId;
private static int courseIdList = 0;

/**
 * 
 */
public Course(String tile)
{
    this.title = title;
    courseId = courseIdList;
    courseIdList++;
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}

/**
 * @param returns the title
 */
public String getTitle(String title)
{
    return title;   
}

/**
 * @return returns the ID
 */
public int getId()
{
    return courseId;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void addStudent(Student students)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    {
        if(students.getId() != students.get(i).getId())
        {
            students.add(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void removeStudent(Student students)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    {
        if(students.getId() == students.get(i).getId())
        {
            students.remove(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return if class is above or equal to 10 then return true, else return false;
 */
public boolean isFull(Student students)
{
    if(students.size() >= 30)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * @returns if the class is below ten then return true, else return false
 */
public boolean cancel(Student students)
{
    if( students.size() < 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public ArrayList<Student> getStudents()
{
    return students;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public boolean inClass(Student students)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    {
        if(student.getId() == students.get(i).getId())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * boolean returns true if a student's ID mathes and false if their ID does not. 
 */
public boolean equals(Student s)
{
    if(this.getId() == s.getId())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public double getAverage()
{
    double sum = 0;

    for(Student s : students)
    {
        sum += s.getGrade();
    }

    double avg = sum / students.size();
    return avg;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void getHighestGrade()
{
    int highestGrade = 0;
    for(Student s : students)
    {
        if(students.getGrade() > s.get(i).getGrade())
        {
            students.highestGrade(i);
        }
    }

    return new Student(" ", 0,0);
}

/**
 * 
 */
public ArrayList<Student> getWarnings()
{
    for(i = 0; i < students.size; i++)
    {
        if (students.getGrade() <= 70)
        {
            return students;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void removeSeniors(Student students)
{
    for(i = 0; i < students.size; i++)
    {
        if(students.getId() == students.get(i).subString(0,2).equalsTo(17))
        {
            students.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void sortByGrade()
{

}

/**
 * 
 */
public void sortByAlpha()
{

}

/**
 * 
 */
public String toString()
{
    String printOut = "";

    printOut += "Course name: " + title + "\nStudent ID: " + courseId;

    return printOut;

    for(Student students : students)
    {
        printOut += students.toString() + "\n";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You pass a `Student` to the method `addStudent` and to many other methods. Not a list of Students. You should pass a list like `List<Student> students`.

Comment: @ottrob THX it worked but now im getting the same error for the getId()? any thoughts on that one?

Answer (score 0):

Now its the opposite :) `students` is a `List` and not a `Student`. You need to loop over the list and process each student.

```
public void doSomething(List<Student> students) {
    // does not work because students is a List of students not a student.
    students.getId(); // ERROR

    // loop over the list and then get the id of a single student
    for(Student student : students) {
        int id = student.getId();
        // do something with the id
    }
}
```

`size()` is a method of the List interface

`getId()` is a method of your Student class.